# How can I combine a character followed by a "combining accent" into a single character?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, internationalization, normalize

**How can I combine a character followed by a "combining accent" into a single character?**

I'm taking a phrase that the user enters into a web page and submitting it to a French-English dictionary. Sometimes the dictionary lookup would fail because there are two representations for most accented characters. For example:

- é can be done in a single character: `\xE9` (latin small letter e with acute).
- But it an also be represented by two characters: `e` + `\u0301` (combining acute accent).

I always want to submit the former (single character) to the dictionary.

Right now, I'm doing that by replacing every two-character occurrence I find with the equivalent single character. But is there a simpler (i.e. one-line) way to do this, either in JavaScript or in the browser when its fetched form the input field?

```
function translate(phrase) {
    // Combine accents into a single accented character, if necessary.
    var TRANSFORM = [
        // Acute accent.
        [/E\u0301/g, "\xC9"], // É
        [/e\u0301/g, "\xE9"], // é

        // Grave accent.
        [/a\u0300/g, "\xE0"], // à
        [/e\u0300/g, "\xE8"], // è
        [/u\u0300/g, "\xF9"], // ù

        // Cedilla (no combining accent).

        // Circumflex.
        [/a\u0302/g, "\xE2"], // â
        [/e\u0302/g, "\xEA"], // ê
        [/i\u0302/g, "\xEE"], // î
        [/o\u0302/g, "\xF4"], // ô
        [/u\u0302/g, "\xFB"], // û

        // Trema.
        [/e\u0308/g, "\xEB"], // ë
        [/i\u0308/g, "\xEF"], // ï
        [/u\u0308/g, "\xFC"] // ü

        // oe ligature (no combining accent).
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < TRANSFORM.length; i++)
        phrase = phrase.replace(TRANSFORM[i][0], TRANSFORM[i][1]);

    // Do translation.
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace) with function and simplify your match into single regex (`.[\\u0300\\u0302]`) and than check match against dictionary of all choices...

Comment: If you are looking for the same thing in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization), it looks like you want NFC normalization:

> Characters are decomposed and then recomposed by canonical equivalence.

Or in other words, it replaces any combined characters with the single character equivalent.

This is built into ECMAScript 6 as [`String.prototype.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize), so if you are fine only supporting newer browsers you could just do the following:

```
phrase = phrase.normalize('NFC');
```

To support older browsers as well, it looks like this library does what you want:
https://github.com/walling/unorm

Usage would be `phrase = UNorm.nfc(phrase)`.

Comment: Thank you! I had trouble searching for an answer because I didn't know what to call it.